# C# - Regex Match whole words

Tags: c#, regex, regex-negation

I need to match all the whole words containing a given a string.

```
string s = "ABC.MYTESTING
XYZ.YOUTESTED
ANY.TESTING";

Regex r = new Regex("(?<TM>[!\..]*TEST.*)", ...);
MatchCollection mc = r.Matches(s);
```

I need the result to be:

```
MYTESTING
YOUTESTED
TESTING
```

But I get:

```
TESTING
TESTED
.TESTING
```

How do I achieve this with Regular expressions.

Edit: Extended sample string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you were looking for all words including 'TEST', you should use

```
@"(?<TM>\w*TEST\w*)"
```

\w includes word characters and is short for [A-Za-z0-9_]

Comment: @tvr: be aware `\w` matches [0-9a-zA-Z_]. If you don't want numbers or underscores, stick with `\b`.

Comment: @Brad: It matches a lot more than that, but the important thing is that it *doesn't* match non-word characters.

Answer (score 2):

Keep it simple: why not just try `\w*TEST\w*` as the match pattern.

Answer (score 2):

I get the results you are expecting with the following:

```
string s = @"ABC.MYTESTING
XYZ.YOUTESTED
ANY.TESTING";

var m = Regex.Matches(s, @"(\w*TEST\w*)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: +1 for verbatim strings and a (probably) correct regex, but `RegexOptions.Multiline` serves no purpose here.

Comment: @alan Right you are, and now removed.  That snuck in from my LINQPad script.

Comment: Yeah, RegexBuddy always sneaks that in, too.  Very annoying.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `\b`. It's the regex flag for a non-word delimiter. If you wanted to match both words you could use:

```
/\b[a-z]+\b/i
```

BTW, .net doesn't need the surrounding `/`, and the `i` is just a case-insensitive match flag.

.NET Alternative:

```
var re = new Regex(@"\b[a-z]+\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: This matches a 1-letter word, not both words.

Comment: Hmm. How do I specify that? I tried this but doesn't work:
Regex r = new Regex("\b(?<TM>[!\..]*TEST.*)\b", ...);

Comment: @mousino: Indeed i did miss a quantifier, but will match both words.

Comment: @tvr: Also, if you want only words starting with "TEST", use `\btest[a-z]+\b`, e.g. http://www.ideone.com/8KNQz

Comment: @Brad Thanks for the sample code. This is small part of a larger regular expression and I cannot change now..

Comment: +1 for pointing me to a [online mini IDE and debugging tool](http://www.ideone.com/) – and your first sentence was the best answer to the OP's original question

Comment: @mousio: Sometimes less is more. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Using Groups I think you can achieve it.

```
        string s = @"ABC.TESTING
        XYZ.TESTED";
        Regex r = new Regex(@"(?<TM>[!\..]*(?<test>TEST.*))", RegexOptions.Multiline);
        var mc= r.Matches(s);
        foreach (Match match in mc)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["test"]);
        }
```

Works exactly like you want.

BTW, your regular expression pattern should be a verbatim string ( @"")

Comment: The `Multiline` option isn't needed here, but `IgnoreCase` might be.  And regarding `[!\..]*`, see my answer.

Comment: Yes, but I was just going with the pattern provided by the OP. The other patterns provided are better.

Comment: Take it from me: it's **never** a good idea to use regexes from a question without validating them.  Or *any* code, for that matter.  Or from other answers.  I've been burned that way too many times. :-/

Answer (score 0):

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"(?<TM>[^.]*TEST.*)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

First, as @manojlds said, you should use verbatim strings for regexes whenever possible.  Otherwise you'll have to use two backslashes in most of your regex escape sequences, not just one (e.g. `[!\\..]*`).

Second, if you want to match anything but a dot, that part of the regex should be `[^.]*`.  `^` is the metacharacter that inverts the character class, not `!`, and `.` has no special meaning in that context, so it doesn't need to be escaped.  But you should probably use `\w*` instead, or even `[A-Z]*`, depending on what exactly you mean by "word".  `[!\..]` matches `!` or `.`.

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"(?<TM>[A-Z]*TEST[A-Z]*)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

That way you don't need to bother with word boundaries, though they don't hurt:

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"(?<TM>\b[A-Z]*TEST[A-Z]*\b)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Finally, if you're always taking the whole match anyway, you don't need to use a capturing group:

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"\b[A-Z]*TEST[A-Z]*\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

The matched text will be available via Match's `Value` property.