# Struggling to match exact regex to my strings

Tags: c#, regex

I have these strings

```
string1 = CD.TR.DRC/TF8
string2 = CD.TR.DRC/TF8/A8
string3 = CD.TR.DRC/TF8.PB
string4 = DRC/TF8
string5 = DDRC/TF8
```

I am trying to match to the regex `DRC/TF8` exactly. So what I want is only `string1`, `string3` and `string4` to return `true`. Could someone please suggest how I could get obtain that using regex?

Comment: "_I am trying to match to the regex DRC/TF8 exactly_" -> but `string1` and `string3` don't match that exactly. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Everyone is going on about regex but I see a question that asks for `true` when a specific string is found inside another string... Why regex? What's wrong with `string.Contains()`? (Also why string 1/2/4 and not 3, it also contains the value you are looking for?)

Comment: Good point. However wouldn't `string.Contains("DRC/TF8")` also match `string5`?

Answer (score 1):

I would say this will work:

`\bDRC\/TF8(?=\.|$)`

- `\b` [binds the whole word](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-boundaries.html#wordboundary)
- `(?=\.|$)` is [negative lookahead](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html) which asserts that the word is terminated with a . or it's the end of the line

See example: https://regexr.com/634a3

Detailed syntax for C# can be found in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5692020/c-sharp-regex-match-whole-words).

Comment: Is the `(?=\.|$)` really necessary? `\b` seems sufficient, and if it wasn't then you could drop the `\b`.

Comment: Yes I guess, as otherwise it would also take `string2`

Comment: Oh right, thank you for the reply. But then the `\b` before `(?=\.|$)` is not necessary anymore.

Comment: Mhh you may be right. Will check and update my answer if necessary

Answer (score 0):

Based on your current examples you can use this pattern: `(?<=\.|^)DRC\/TF8(?=\.|$)`

code:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Test{
    public static void Main(){
        string pattern = @"(?<=\.|^)DRC\/TF8(?=\.|$)";  
        Regex re = new Regex(pattern);  
        string[] text = {"CD.TR.DRC/TF8", "CD.TR.DRC/TF8/A8", "CD.TR.DRC/TF8.PB", "DRC/TF8", "DDRC/TF8"};
        foreach(string str in text){
            if (re.IsMatch(str)){
                Console.WriteLine(str);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

output:

```
CD.TR.DRC/TF8
CD.TR.DRC/TF8.PB
DRC/TF8
```

Comment: It's unlikely that the examples in the question are exhaustive.